# Get json field value with JQ from different directory

Tags: bash, jq

Title may be incorrect as I'm not actually sure where this is failing. I have a bash script running in one directory, and a JSON file I need a value from in a different directory. I want to copy the value from the external directory into an identical JSON file in the current directory.

I'm using jq to grab the value, but I can't figure out how to grab from a directory other than the one the script is running in.

The relevant bits of file structure are as follows;

```
cloudformation
  - parameters_v13.json
environment_files
  - prepare_stack_files.json (the script this is run from)
  - directory, changes based on where the script is pointed
      - created directory where created files are being output
         - GREPNAME_parameters.json
```

The chunk of the JSON file I'm interested in looks like this;

```
[ 
{
   "ParameterKey": "RTSMEMAIL",
   "ParameterValue": "secretemail"
  }
]
```

The script needs to get the "secretemail" from `cloudformation/parameters_v13.json`  and paste it into the matching RTSMEMAIL field in the `GREPNAME_parameters.json` file.

I've been attempting the following with no luck - nothing is output. No error message either, just blank output. I know the GREPNAME path is correct because it's used elsewhere with no issues.

```
jq --arg email "$EMAIL" '(.[] | select(.ParameterKey == "RTSMEMAIL") | .ParameterValue) |= $email' ../cloudformation/parameters_v13.json | sponge ${GREPNAME}_parameters.json
```

Comment: Your input is not verifiable, if only you can provide the complete `json` or a sample file, would be helpful.

Comment: Right sorry, put brackets in so it should count for a complete file

Comment: What do you expect from `jq --arg email "$EMAIL" '(.[] | select(.ParameterKey == "RTSMEMAIL") | .ParameterValue) |= $email'`, it is giving me blank output.

Comment: I'm expecting `secretemail` - the blank output is exactly why I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `jq` filter should help you get `secretmail` string

```
jq '.[] | select(.ParameterKey=="RTSMEMAIL") | .ParameterValue' json
"secretemail"
```

Add a `-r` file for raw output to remove quotes around the value

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.ParameterKey=="RTSMEMAIL") | .ParameterValue' json
secretemail
```

> --raw-output / -r:
>
> With this option, if the filter’s result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based systems.

As I could see it you are trying to pass `args` to `jq` filter, for extraction you can do something first by setting the variable in `bash`

```
email="RTSMEMAIL"
```

and now pass it to the filter as

```
jq --arg email "$email" -r '.[] | select(.ParameterKey==$email) | .ParameterValue' json 
secretemail
```

Now to replace the string obtained from `parameters_v13.json` file to your `GREPNAME_parameters.json` do the following steps:-

First storing the result from the first file in a variable to re-use later, I have used the file to extract as `json`, this actually points your `parameters_v13.json` file in another path.

```
replacementValue=$(jq --arg email "$email" -r '.[] | select(.ParameterKey==$email) | .ParameterValue' json)
```

now the `$replacementValue` will hold the `secretmail` which you want to update to another file. As you have indicated previously `GREPNAME_parameters.json` has a similar syntax as of the first file. Something like below,

```
$ cat GREPNAME_parameters.json
[ 
{
   "ParameterKey": "SOMEJUNK",
   "ParameterValue": "somejunkvalue"
  }
]
```

Now I understand your intention is replace `"ParameterValue"` from the above file to the value obtained from the other file. To achieve that,

```
jq --arg replace "$replacementValue" '.[] | .ParameterValue = $replace' GREPNAME_parameters.json
{
  "ParameterKey": "SOMEJUNK",
  "ParameterValue": "secretemail"
}
```

You can then write this output to the a temp file and move it back as the `GREPNAME_parameters.json`. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but it doesn't actually solve my problem, which is that I am trying to select the value from one file and move it into another. It's not the value that's the issue, it's the pathing.

Comment: @Alex: You want to feed this value to another command is what you intend to do?

Comment: In brief, I want to copy the secretemail from the `parameters_v13.json` file into the `GREPNAME_parameters.json file.

Comment: How can you copy a string to another file? @Alex, write it ? Append it at end?

Comment: I'm super new to bash / jq so that's where I'm stumped. I thought I could use the command I did to extract the value from the v13 file and then sponge it into the grepname file, but that doesn't seem to be working. If you know another way please let me know.

Comment: @Alex: I can for sure, but I am not sure I understand when you say `sponge it` into another file? What exactly is that you want to achieve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131822/discussion-between-inian-and-alex).

Comment: The grepname file will be created with an old secretemail value. I want to copy the secretemail from the v13 file into the grepname file, overwriting the existing value. I say sponge it because I'm using moreutils' `sponge` command to write back into the file. I was told it (and jq) are the best way to work with JSON files.

Comment: @Alex: Refer my update which should solve your problem hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex -

(1) `sponge` simply provides a convenient way to modify a file without having to manage a temporary file.  You could use it like this:

```
jq  ........ input.json | sponge input.json
```

Here, "input.json" is the file that you want to edit "in place".  If you want to avoid overwriting the input file, you would not use `sponge`.  In fact, I would recommend against doing so until you're absolutely sure that's what you want.

(2) There are several strategies for achieving what you have described using jq. They basically fall into two categories: (a) invoke jq twice; (b) invoke jq once.

Ignoring the `sponge` part:

- the pattern for using jq twice would be as follows:

  ```
  param=$(jq -r '.[]
    | select(.ParameterKey == "RTSMEMAIL")|.ParameterValue
    ' cloudformation/parameters_v13.json )

  jq --arg param "$param" -f edit.jq input.json
  ```
- assuming you have jq 1.5, the pattern for doing everything with just one invocation of jq would be:

  ```
  jq --argfile p cloudformation/parameters_v13.json -f manage.jq input.json
  ```

Here, edit.jq and manage.jq are files containing suitable jq programs.

Based on my understanding of your requirements, edit.jq might look like this:

```
(.[] | select(.ParameterKey == "RTSMEMAIL")|.ParameterValue) |= $param
```

And manage.jq might look like this:

```
($p[] | select(.ParameterKey == "RTSMEMAIL")|.ParameterValue) as $param
| (.[]| select(.ParameterKey == "RTSMEMAIL")|.ParameterValue) |= $param
```