# Using JQ to generate AWS CloudFormation Parameters File

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, jq

Trying to generate an AWS Parameter file using JQ for use in a call to CloudFormation

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name test --parameters file://params.json --template-body file://cfn.yaml
```

I was thinking of taking template like this:

```
'[{"ParameterKey":"KEY","ParameterValue":"VALUE","UsePreviousValue":false}]'
```

And then adding some parameters in JQ and trying to do some string operations on an arg such as jq --arg params 'key1,value1:key2,value2' then split on ':' to duplicate it and populate each with the comma separated values.

The best I can do is create the correct number of top level nodes ahead of time and then do a static replacement, supplying each argument individually.  Not dynamic enough to even bother -- better to just write a bash script and do substitutions in a loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Currently the best I've been able to do is this

```
echo '[{"ParameterKey":"KEY","ParameterValue":"VALUE","UsePreviousValue":false}]' | jq --arg vars "key1,val1:key2,val2" '.[0].ParameterKey = ($vars|split(":")|.[]|split(",")|.[0]) | .[0].ParameterValue = ($vars|split(":")|.[]|split(",")|.[1])'
```

But the output is a combination of all values (e.g. key1 val1, key1 val2, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using `--argfile`.  Here are some answers that demonstrate it:

- [replace json node with another json file with command line jq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43058133/8379597)
- [Value map with JQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31890081/8379597)
- [Update one JSON file values with values from another JSON using JQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44855405/8379597)

Comment: I guess the idea was to pass some variable from a jenkins job into a template and make it dynamic enough that the Jenkins pipeline code can be reused without changes.  This way a cfn template and list of parameters can be specified outside of the groovy code.  If i have to create a json file to use for jq then I might as well create the cfn parameters file using the same tool (not jq)

Comment: That sounds reasonable.  Also here's another answer that may be of interest to you: [Get json field value with JQ from different directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41387346/8379597), specifically `jq --argfile p cloudformation/parameters_v13.json -f manage.jq input.json`